# RestAssured: Assert Json response which has single object response fails due to not started with curly brace '{' or an openning square bracket '['

Tags: rest-assured, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

We have scenario where there is GET API call which extracts "excel" file data from file given file location in the GET call Body.

Using: RestAssured with Cucumber BDD

**The Response comes as:**

```
"{\"('Test\/Test1', 'Text')\":{\"0\":\"abc\",\"1\":null,},\"('Test ID', 'Text')\":....:null}}"
```

Trying to have "Assert" to the text value coming in the Response body.

**Tried below ways:**

```
String details = response.jsonPath().get("Test\/Test1");

System.out.println("loan details value is: " + details);
```

Getting error as:

```
io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:986)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:951)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:1031)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:202)
at com.xxx.stepdefinition.Co_APIs_StepDen.extract_validated_successfully(Core_APIs_StepDen.java:62)
at ?.Validate the extracted details are retrieved successfully(C:/Users//src/test/java/com/Co_POST_ExtractDetails.feature:17)
```

Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: A JSON payload should start with an openning curly brace '{' or an openning square bracket '['.
Instead, '"{"('Test/Test1', 'Text')":

Please guide.

Comment: Are you trying to assert that the string in the response contains "Test\/Test1"?

Comment: How does your response look like ? Does it `exactly` look like the one you have posted with the double quotes ? Post the exact response

Comment: @WojtekT yes, trying to validate/assert to check the 'string' value in the response body.

Comment: The JSON which is fetched back has escape characters in it, and using `.jsonpath()` will not help here since the JSON should be proper. Either extract the response as string and unescape the characters and then use `jsonPath` or extract the response as string and assert on the same string using Hamcrest `assertThat(res,containsString("Test\\/Test1"));`